# How can I modify this image to make it more readable?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to use tesseract (an OCR software) from a PHP script (through the `exec()` command).

I have created the following image by using the PHP `image_filter()` function:

```
imagefilter($dest, IMG_FILTER_NEGATE);
imagefilter($dest, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000);
```

[image: tiff 50wx25h]

However this image isn't recognized correctly by tesseract, because of two factor (in my opinion, I'm not an expert) :

1. The image is too small - it would be better to resize it to 100x50 (now is 50x25).
2. The digits are too close each other - I need a method to separate them a little bit.

How can I solve this issue?
I can use Imagemagick if needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: P.S. I've tried `$exec = "/usr/local/bin/convert -resize 200% a.tif";` But it creates a blurred image and obviously it isn't recognized properly.

Comment: Did you try `-adaptive-resize` with convert?

Comment: yes but it doens't work either :(

Comment: This probably won't help for your problem since you want to use some specific pre-existing image, but do note that php's Image Magick (and Image Magick in general) can make a black "150" on a white background of any size and of any file type.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't the case :D Do you know if there is the possibility of separate digits with Imagemagick or PHP?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you can do it with any string: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Comment: I mean now I have 150 , maybe OCR is easier if the image would be 1 5 0 ... :D